# Reporting solution for a 100,000 user base website, rrd?

Tags: reporting, rrdtool

Customer's website is a 100,000 user base website with million records of transaction data, currently the site uses RRDTool to generate several reports for every user in scheduled jobs, the concerns are:

- Not every user will need to view this report.
- Due to some reasons, the RRDTool can't always generate the reports on time. It seems the RRDTool could't finish generating report for so many users in a specified period, before next scheduled job start.
- There're 100,000 sub-folders under the rrdtool, each represent one user.

Please advice whether this is the good use case to use RRDTool as the reporting solution, if not what might be a better solution in this case? Thanks in advance.

Edit:
The report graph is actually very simple, just plotted or trend line graphs, is it possible to simply use SQL query to fetch the data and then use Javascript library (such as gRaphaël) to render the chart in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at www.extopus.org it might build the basis for something that can create reports on the fly. I guess not all your users are looking at reports all the time ... so creating them on demand might make more sense ...

if you are not storing data in rrdtool, then it may indeed make sense to draw the charts on canvas ... jqplot might help ... extopus could be enhanced for this too, the architecture is very flexible ...